# Store Values based on Key in PHP Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to store values from the following $cart_item array:

```
[addons] => Array( 
    [0] => Array(
        [name] => First Name - First Name
        [value] => Gary
        [price] =>
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [name] => Church Information - Name
        [value] => Victory Bible Church
        [price] =>
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [name] => Shirt Size
        [value] => XL
        [price] =>
    )
)
```

I've realized that I can't grab the value based on the index because this array will sometimes have more sub arrays. For example, I can't use the following string to store data:

```
$shirt_size = $cart_item['addons'][2]['value'];
```

Because someone might add into the array the name "Church Information - City" and that will take the array index of [2], which will then make the $shirt_size variable take the 'Church Information - City' value. I don't want that happening.

There are only 2 other possible arrays that will be included. I want to store all possible values associated with a name.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Where is the code that generates the above array?

Comment: @Mooseman this array comes from the WooCommerce plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each of the values in variables, you can use value of 'name' key to store value of 'value' key.

```
foreach ($cart_item['addons'] as $key => $val) {
    $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ','_', $val['name']));
    $$name = $val['value'];
}

echo $shirt_size; //output as XL
```

OR

if you want only the shirt size, then you can apply a condition and get your value.

```
foreach ($cart_item['addons'] as $key => $val) {
    if ($val['name'] == 'Shirt Size') {
        $shirt_size = $val['value'];
    }
}

echo $shirt_size; //output as XL
```

Hope this will help you to grab the required values.

Comment: Thanks @v2solutions Once again, the answer seems to be so simple after I see it.